# 'A' to Ä converter

Tags: code-golf, string

I'm currently scanning a bunch of handwritten documents and converting them to `.txt` files. Since I have a terrible handwriting the `.jpg`->`.txt` converter converts some of my umlauts to the *"normal"* letter encased by `'`

### Task

Write a program or a function that:

- Is given a string

  - you can choose any I/O codepage as long as

    - it supports the characters `AEIOUaeiouÄËÏÖÜäëïöü'`.

      - [combining diacriticals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks) are prohibited
    - the Input and Output codepages are the same.
  - the input will (beside spaces) only contain printable characters from your codepage.

    - There will only be one solution, thus things like `'a'e'` won't appear
- Converts all characters in the following set `AEIOUaeiou` to `ÄËÏÖÜäëïöü`

  - If, and only if, they are surrounded by `'` characters:

    - ***Example***: `'a''e' -> äë`
  - If the ***from*** string is a single letter.

    - for example `'AE'` does not change at all, outputting as-is.
  - If the ***from*** character is not a character out of `AEIOUaeiou` that character won't change.

Note: The ***from character / from string*** is the one between `'`.

### Testcases

```
Input
Output
<empty line>

'A'sthetik
Ästhetik

Meinung ist wichtig!
Meinung ist wichtig!

Ich sagte: "Er sagte: 'Ich habe Hunger'"
Ich sagte: "Er sagte: 'Ich habe Hunger'"

Ich sagte: "Er sagte: ''A'sthetik'"
Ich sagte: "Er sagte: 'Ästhetik'"

Hämisch rieb er sich die H'a'nde
Hämisch rieb er sich die Hände

H'a''a'slich isn't a German word
Hääslich isn't a German word

since it's really called h'a'sslich
since it's really called hässlich
```

Comment: The active ingredient in all of your testcases are either `'A'` or `'a'`... not what I consider good testcases.

Comment: Can you add a example with `'w'` (as `w` is not one of `AEIOUaeiou`)?

Comment: Combining diacriticals had [unknown status](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118466/a-to-%c3%84-converter/118499?noredirect=1#comment290211_118466), then [were allowed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118466/a-to-%c3%84-converter/118499?noredirect=1#comment290285_118466), then were [disallowed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118466/a-to-%c3%84-converter/118499?noredirect=1#comment290289_118466).  This invalidated at least 4 answers.  Boo! Hiss! I've changed my upvote to a downvote :(

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I'm very sorry for that.

Comment: Add testcase: `'q'e'd'`

Comment: What is with strings like `'a'u'`, this can result in `äu`, `aü` or `äü`, what of that is allowed what not?

Comment: Isn't it häßlich?

Comment: [This](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/haesslich) says it is `hässlich`. In the first example the error(?) is intended.

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>81</s> <s>70</s> 68 bytes

```js
s=>s.replace(/'[aeiou]'/gi,c=>"ï   ÖÄöä ËÜëüÏ "[c.charCodeAt(1)%15])
```

---

### Try It

```js
f=
s=>s.replace(/'[aeiou]'/gi,c=>"ï   ÖÄöä ËÜëüÏ "[c.charCodeAt(1)%15])
i.addEventListener("input",_=>o.innerText=f(i.value))
console.log(f("'A'sthetik")) // Ästhetik
console.log(f("Meinung ist wichtig!")) // Meinung ist wichtig!
console.log(f(`Ich sagte: "Er sagte: 'Ich habe Hunger'"`)) // Ich sagte: "Er sagte: 'Ich habe Hunger'"
console.log(f(`Ich sagte: "Er sagte: ''A'sthetik'"`)) // Ich sagte: "Er sagte: 'Ästhetik'"
console.log(f("Hämisch rieb er sich die H'a'nde")) // Hämisch rieb er sich die Hände
console.log(f("H'a''a'slich isn't a German word")) // Hääslich isn't a German word
console.log(f("since it's really called h'a'sslich")) // since it's really called hässlich
```

```html
<input id=i><pre id=o>
```

---

### Explanation

- `s=>` Anonymous function taking the input string as an argument via parameter "s".
- `s.replace(x,y)` Returns the string with "x" replaced by "y".
- `/'[aeiou]'/gi` Case insensitive regular expression that matches all occurrences of a vowel enclosed by single quotes.
- `c=>` Passes each match of the regular expression to an anonymous function via parameter "c".
- `"ï   ÖÄöä ËÜëüÏ "[n]` Returns the nth character (0 indexed) in the string "ï   ÖÄöä ËÜëüÏ ", similar to `"ï   ÖÄöä ËÜëüÏ ".charAt(n)`.
- `c.charCodeAt(1)%15` Gets the remainder of the character code of the second character in "c" (i.e. the vowel character) when divided by 15.

---

### Alternative, <s>40/52</s> 36/48 bytes (35/47 characters)

The following was my answer before combining diacritics were disallowed (Boo-urns!) - better viewed in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/petershaggynoble/wgubutt4/)

```
s=>s.replace(/'([aeiou])'/gi,"$1̈")
```

However, [ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions) suggests that with the addition of `.normalize()` for an additional 12 bytes that this would be valid.

```
s=>s.replace(/'([aeiou])'/gi,"$1̈").normalize()
```

Comment: OP still hasn't answered https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59183/dzaima

Comment: No, if combining diacritics are allowed.

Comment: Combining diacritics are now prohibited.

Comment: I believe you can make this valid by adding `.normalize()` to the end of the function.

Comment: Are you sure, @ETHproductions? If combining diacritics are prohibited, are they not prohibited from appearing in an answer *at all*?

Answer (score 8):

## Perl 5, 25 bytes

```
s/'(\w)'/chr 1+ord$1/age
```

24 bytes, plus 1 for `-pe` instead of `-e`

This makes use of the rule that "you can choose any I/O codepage as long as it supports the characters `AEIOUaeiouÄËÏÖÜäëïöü'`". It also makes use of the `/a` flag on regexes, which causes `\w` to refer to precisely the characters in `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_0123456789` no matter how they're encoded.

The chosen I/O codepage for my script is this:

```
 1  a
 2  ä
 3  e
 4  ë
 5  i
 6  ï
 7  o
 8  ö
 9  u
10  ü
11  A
12  Ä
13  E
14  Ë
15  I
16  Ï
17  O
18  Ö
19  U
20  Ü
21  '
```

(I can't test this script on the test cases in the question, as they include some really weird characters, like `t`.)

---

Thanks to [Grimy](/users/6484/grimy) for saving me three bytes. Earlier, I had `s/'([a-z])'/chr 1+ord$1/gie`, which made use of (the encoding and) the interesting fact that `[a-z]` is special-cased in Perl to match precisely `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` no matter the encoding. My earlier answer is, IMO, more interesting, but this one is shorter, so, what the heck, I'll take it.

Comment: I carefully checked the "loopholes that are forbidden by default" list before posting this, and inventing a codepage wasn't among them. That, plus especially the fact that the question invited use of "any I/O codepage", seem to allow this answer. And then the `a-z` trick makes the answer actually interesting instead of merely a cheat. (IMO, anyway.)

Comment: This is the kind of trick that’s only funny once, but I believe you’re the first one to use it, so it works (=

Comment: You could save 3 bytes by using `\w` instead of `[a-z]`, as well as `/a` instead of `/i`. If the "/a" modifier is in effect, `\w` matches the characters [a-zA-Z0-9_], regardless of how they’re encoded.

Comment: @Grimy, thanks! I'll edit....

Answer (score 6):

## Vim, 33 bytes

```
:s/\c'\([aeiou]\)'/<C-v><C-k>\1:/g
ii<esc>D@"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@29VrB@TrB6jEZ2YmplfGhujqa4vxh1jaKWfzpWZKe3ioPT/v4d6ojoQFedkJmcoZBbnqZcoJCqkpxblJuYplOcXpQAA) in the backwards compatible V interpreter.

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 29 bytes

```
r"'%v'"@"ï   ÖÄöä ËÜëüÏ "gXc1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#AUoAtf//ciInJXYnIkAiw68gICDDlsOEw7bDpCDDi8Ocw6vDvMOPICJnWGMx//8iJ0EnJ0UnJ0knJ08nJ1UnJ2EnJ2UnJ2knJ28nJ3UnIg)

#### Explanation

```
r"'%v'"@"ï   ÖÄöä ËÜëüÏ "gXc1

r"'%v'"@                       // Replace each match X of /'<vowel>'/ in the input with
        "ï   ÖÄöä ËÜëüÏ "g     //   the character in this string at index
                          Xc1  //     X.charCodeAt(1).
                               //   Values larger than the length of the string wrap around,
                               //   so this is effectively equal to " ... "[n%15].
                               // Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Comment: Using combining diacritics is controversial.

Comment: Beat me to it. Your solution is much shorter than mine though... Well done.

Comment: @LeakyNun Controversial for this question or in general?

Comment: Controversial for this question because you raised it in the comments but it was never addressed.

Comment: @Adám Beat you by 38 seconds ;-)

Comment: @ETHproductions Ninja'ed :-D

Comment: @LeakyNun Fixed now.

Comment: Can you add an explanation please?

Comment: @Luke Added now, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: It's not too different from what I expected. I started writing a solution which doesn't use the wrapping of string indexing (since I didn't know Japt had that), but that is much longer.

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript, 67 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/'.'/g,c=>"äëïöüÄËÏÖÜ"['aeiouAEIOU'.indexOf(c[1])]||c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY@xSgNBEIZ7n2K8Zu9AL9gqF0gRTApJZRUC2ezN3Y1udsPOxiiktLOws7JMZ2FnZbcPdu4JIsg1wjAMM/P988@NvJOsHG38qbEltlXRcjHk3OFGS4XpQORiUJ@oYpiEQ3gL7@EjfIbH8BSew0t4TeZCItntaDydXYucTIn3sypV87NFttjvVdYqa9hqzLWt0ypdipFg36Cn22WWXRz9mV4hma2pgdjDjlTjqT7u25uqBljWHs8hGbufUnTtRq4QJlEEnUj@wf4a68cm4bAmjqwjXAFGMPqDkuIxIUX8uxeKoxisu11iIzxIuES3lgZ21pV9DJNRCOQFg0Op9QOomLGEplP6luqw9gs)

Replace all characters between quotes with either the corresponding umlauted character, or the match itself if it's not in the group of characters that need changing.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 36 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
œṣ⁹Ṫ¤j
“.ạẏụ’D196;+\Ọż⁾''jÐ€Øc¤;@Wç/
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#AV0Aov//xZPhuaPigbnhuarCpGoK4oCcLuG6oeG6j@G7peKAmUQxOTY7K1zhu4zFvOKBvicnasOQ4oKsw5hjwqQ7QFfDpy////8iRXIgc2FndGU6ICcnQSdzdGhldGlrJyI)**

This seems pretty complicated for Jelly!

#### How?

Note: Since the characters are not on the code-page, but are within the range of a byte in Unicode I think they must be created from ordinals, so I have.

```
œṣ⁹Ṫ¤j - Link 1, Replace: char list S [...], list R [char T, char list F]
œṣ     - split S at sublists equal to:
    ¤  -   nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
  ⁹    -     link's right argument, R
   Ṫ   -     tail - yield char list F and modify R to become [T]
     j - join with R (now [T])
       - all in all split S at Rs and join back up with [T]s.

“.ạẏụ’D196;+\Ọż⁾''jÐ€Øc¤;@Wç/ - Main link: char list S
       196;                   - 196 concatenate with:
“.ạẏụ’                        -   base 250 literal 747687476
      D                       -   to decimal list [7,4,7,6,8,7,4,7,6]
           +\                 - cumulative reduce with addition: [196,203,207,214,220,228,235,239,246,252]
             Ọ                - cast to characters: ÄËÏÖÜäëïöü
                       ¤      - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
               ⁾''            -   literal ["'", "'"]
                     Øc       -   vowel yield: AEIOUaeiou
                  jÐ€         -   join mapped:  ["'A'", "'E'", ...]
              ż               - zip together
                          W   - wrap S in a list
                        ;@    - concatenate (swap @rguments)
                           ç/ - reduce with last link (1) as a dyad
                              - implicit print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 24 bytes

```
Óã'¨[aeiou]©'/±:
éiD@"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@3948uHF6odWRCemZuaXxh5aqa4vxn1ooxXX4ZWZLg5K//97qCeqA1FxTmZyhkJmcZ56iUKiQnpqUW5inkJ5flEKAA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: d3e3 27a8 5b61 6569 6f75 5da9 272f 160b  ..'.[aeiou].'/..
00000010: b13a 0ae9 6944 4022                      .:..iD@"
```

This is just a direct translation of my vim answer so that I can beat all of the golfing languages. :P

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 62+1 = 63 bytes

Uses the `-p` flag for +1 byte.

```ruby
gsub(/'([aeiou])'/i){$1.tr"AEIOUaeiou","ÄËÏÖÜäëïöü"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#U1YsKk2qVNAt@J9eXJqkoa@uEZ2YmplfGquprp@pWa1iqFdSpOTo6ukfChZW0lE63HK4@3D/4WmH5xxecnj14fWHtx3eo1T7/79ncoZCcWJ6SaqVgpJrEYypru6oXlySkVqSma2uBAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 53 bytes

```apl
(v←'''[AEIOUaeiou]''')⎕R{'  ÄËÏÖÜäëïöü'[v⍳2⊃⍵.Match]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#jZCxTsMwEIb3PsXRxbB0YGTrUKkdKiQkpqqDm1zjE4ldbCcFISYQAyjAAhMwdWNgQDCx@U38IsGuVEGYsKzT@ff3352umfur@@0qBMbYpD8Y7R9yJFVOw3PH3z4cnDEAd@lu3J17dE9u5V7dm/t0X2xS@fp9119f@PqjN@Y2EdPzpoH1mYOvX2Li62dYIpQG14pVkKGFnCxqngPJRWlhrlUBViBIPIl/EsGo6EqVZBYErzAa0SR8gWvQkMxyhONSWTS9TudX0w7rMxMYS0cteYwkS5kBGQtLSoSlbKsFjBIBhmcW96A70JuURVnwGcIwuFGz7n9MPzP84YduVZAJJk04AwyOMAqkFMozzmSKbTpo4Zo8QmTiMnjYny64hKXSaQsOO0kQyDIDGnmen0ISIqYgNiW@AQ)

Uses PCRE *R*eplace (saving the RegEx as *v*) to apply the following function to quoted vowels:

`{` anonymous function

`'  ÄËÏÖÜäëïöü'[`…`]` index the string (note two spaces corresponding to `'[`) with:

`⍵.Match` the matched string

`2⊃` pick second letter (the vowel)

`v⍳` find index in *v*

`}`

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 67 bytes

```
/~/'\///`/\/\/~/'A~Ä`E~Ë`I~Ï`O~Ö`U~Ü`a~ä`e~ë`i~ï`o~ö`u~ü/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/slashes#@69fp68eo6@vn6AfA4RAjmPd4ZYE17rD3QmedYf7E/zrDk9LCK07PCchse7wkoTUusOrEzLrDq9PyK87vC2htO7wHv3//wE)

This works by replacing non-dotted letters surrounded by single-quotes(`'A'`) with the same letter as a dotted, without the single quotes (`Ä`). A single replacement of this looks like this (before the golf): `/'A'/Ä/`.

The golf takes two common occurrences, `//` and `'/`, and uses them as replacements.

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>43</s> 35 (UTF-8) bytes

```
L∫:ÆW ':h++;"äëïöü”:U+Wŗ
```

Explanation:

```
L∫                        repeat 10 times, pushing current iteration (0-based)
  :                       duplicate the iteration
   ÆW                     get the index (1-based) in "aeiouAEIOU"
      ':h++               quote it
           ;              put the copy (current iteration) ontop
            "äëïöü”       push "äëïöü"
                   :      duplicate it
                    U     uppercase it
                     +    join together, resulting in "äëïöüÄËÏÖÜ"
                      W   get the index (1-based) in it
                       ŗ  replace [in the input, current char from "aeiouAEIOU" with
                          the corresponding char in "äëïöüÄËÏÖÜ"
```

Comment: Heh, one could think that `̈+` is a function in SOGL.

Comment: Combining diacritics are now prohibited.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift - 201 bytes

```
import Foundation;func g(s:String){var e=s;var r="aeiouAEIOUäëïöüÄËÏÖÜ".characters.map{String($0)};for i in r[0...9]{e=e.replacingOccurrences(of:"'\(i)'",with:r[r.index(of:i)!+10])};print(e)}
```

Usage: `g("'A'sthetik")      // => Ästhetik`

Comment: `characters.map{blah blah}` and `replacingOccurrences()` really kill the fun :((

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 99 bytes

```
{split("AEIOUaeiou",p,"")
for(i=1;i<=split("ÄËÏÖÜäëïöü",r,"");i++)gsub("'"p[i]"'",r[i])}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/awk#dY0xT8NADIX3@xXmlkvULF0pHTpUNEPViQkxXBKTWKSX6O6iCiE2NgY2JsZuDGxMbP5hwUFUTEiW35P9PXt8CH1LMdGrdb67skjdoLM@0zpVt51PaDlf0MXyl@EnfuYXfuU3PvI7f/Anf@nMT/SCZrO0DkORaKP7a7oRybxo@jgfx9z1Q1TKrEyIDUa6U2qL5AZXA4UIByqbSPWZUnnZQLB1xHPQa3@yZho3tkDYSAS90f@Sfy8maMPHPQUhPWEBKJh8gorkkLHGVSiIGKnQThsKzkSwcIl@bx0cOl8pFciVCBRNAI@2be@hlI4VNFPuJ6i@AQ)

I tried to come up with some clever regex within a `gensub` but failed :(

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3.6, <s>98</s> 92 characters

```python
import re;a=lambda i,p="'([AEIOUaeiou])'":re.sub(p,lambda x:'ÄËÏÖÜäëïöü'[p.index(x[1])-3],i)
```

It's a function, not a complete program.

Formatted for readability:

```python
import re

a = lambda i, p="'([AEIOUaeiou])'":\
    re.sub(p, lambda x: 'ÄËÏÖÜäëïöü'[p.index(x[1]) - 3], i)
```

Thanks to @ValueInk for clever tips for further golfing.

Comment: Does not run for me. Stops with a TypeError.

Comment: @totallyhuman are you sure? It seems to be working for me. You need to call the `a` function with the string you want to replace.

Comment: [Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@5@SmqaQqJGpaZWZW5BfVKJQlGpdYKukHu3o6ukfmpiamV8aq65kXZRaUlqUB5TUKy5N0ijQyUnMTUpJVKiwUj/ccrj7cP/haYfnHF5yePXh9Ye3Hd6jHl2gl5mXklqhURFtEBttGKupaxSrk6n5v6AoM69EI1FDSd1RvbgkI7UkM1tJU/M/AA)

Comment: @totallyhuman it works for me. Which Python version do you have?

Comment: Python docs reports that `match.__getitem__(g)` is new to Python 3.6 so it should probably be specified in your header. Also, if you change your regex to `'([AEIOUaeiou])'` you save a byte by changing `x[0][1]` to `x[1]` and use `-3` instead of `-2`.

Comment: Actually, it's even shorter to go `import re;a=lambda i,p="'([AEIOUaeiou])'":re.sub ...` since you cut out quite a bit of overhead from no longer needing a `return` statement!

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>30</s> <s>29</s> 24 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to Emigna

```
žMDu«S''«''ì"äëïöü"Du«S:
```

05AB1E conveniently has the characters `äëïöü` in its code page.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@@95dJ@vS@mh1cHq6odWq6sfXqN0eMnh1YfXH952eI8SWMLq/3/1RHUdBfVUEJEJIvJBRCmIcAQRriDCE0T4g4hQEJGYqg4A)

(old code)

```
žMDu«Svy''.ø})"äëïöü"Du«¹ŠS:
```

Explanation (outdated):

```
žM                             Push aeiou                    ['aeiou']
  D                            Duplicate                     ['aeiou', 'aeiou']
   u                           Uppercase                     ['aeiou', 'AEIOU']
    «                          Concatenate                   ['aeiouAEIOU']
     vy                        For each...
       ''                        Push '
         .ø                      Surround a with b (a -> bab)
           }                   End loop
            )                  Wrap stack to array           [["'a'", "'e'", "'i'", "'o'", "'u'", "'A'", "'E'", "'I'", "'O'", "'U'"]]
             "äëïöü"           String literal.               [["'a'", "'e'", "'i'", "'o'", "'u'", "'A'", "'E'", "'I'", "'O'", "'U'"], 'äëïöü']
                    Du«        Duplicate, uppercase, concat  [["'a'", "'e'", "'i'", "'o'", "'u'", "'A'", "'E'", "'I'", "'O'", "'U'"], 'äëïöüÄËÏÖÜ']
                       ¹       Push first input
                        Š      Push c, a, b                  ["'A'sthetik", ["'a'", "'e'", "'i'", "'o'", "'u'", "'A'", "'E'", "'I'", "'O'", "'U'"], 'äëïöüÄËÏÖÜ']
                          S    Convert to char list          ["'A'sthetik", ["'a'", "'e'", "'i'", "'o'", "'u'", "'A'", "'E'", "'I'", "'O'", "'U'"], ['ä', 'ë', 'ï', 'ö', 'ü', 'Ä', 'Ë', 'Ï', 'Ö', 'Ü']]
                           :   Replace all                   ['Ästhetik']
                               Implicit print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@@95dJ@vS@mh1cHq6odWq6sfXqN0eMnh1YfXH952eI8SWMLq/3/1RHUdBfVUEJEJIvJBRCmIcAQRriDCE0T4g4hQEJGYqg4A)

Comment: You could replace `.Á` with `Š`.

Comment: You could save a few more bytes with `žMDu«S''«''ì"äëïöü"Du«S:`

Comment: @Emigna Thanks again.

Comment: You also don't need the `I` at the beginning :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 39 bytes

```
iT`A\EI\OUaei\ou'`ÄËÏÖÜäëïöü_`'[aeiou]'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#dY2xbsJADIb3PIXL4nfoxhARhoqlnQgil8TKWQ0X6e4ixM7GwMbEyMbAxsTmB0sdpIoJybIt/9//e@DvYpqn83zxY4jzrsdC9nKQo5zkLBe5yk3u8lgXuFS961c4DDjFEC1F/k2@iF3vGuAQYcuVjdx8JPPKQjBNpE@YpP5/xfFsTUmQqYM8Tt6Br3xlMrlsOCjomUogpfQN1KwxaNDVlIxTK7SjwMFhBAMz8hvjYNv5OgnsKgKOGMCTadsdVNqpBjvanr4/)