# Wir hassen Umlaute! (We hate umlauts!)

Tags: code-golf, text-processing

## Introduction

As you all know, German has umlauts. They're these things: `¨`

However, most keyboards don't have an umlaut key. That's fine, though, because you can write `ö`, `ä`, and `ü` as `oe`, `ae`, and `ue`.

## Challenge

- Your job is to to replace `ö`, `ä`, and `ü` with `oe`, `ae`, and `ue` (and likewise for their capital versions).
- You have to deal with both the combining diacritical mark and single characters. (Thank you @ETHProductions for pointing this out.)
- Capitalization of the base letter stays intact.
- Capitalization of the `e` depends on the capitalization of the surrounding letters after replacement. You should write it as `e` unless it's adjacent to a capital letter on both sides, in which case write it as `E`. (End of line and space are not capital letters.)
- Standard loopholes and I/O rules apply.
- This is code-golf, so shortest code in **UTF-8** bytes wins!

## Example Input and Output

**Test cases using precomposed characters**

```
ü = ue
üb = ueb
üB = ueB
Ü = Ue
Üb = Ueb
ÜB = UEB
```

**Test cases using combining diacritics**

```
ö = oe
öb = oeb
öB = oeB
Ö = Oe
Öb = Oeb
ÖB = OEB
```

Comment: [Inverse](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/149292/43319).

Comment: I feel like this is [highly related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/149292/parse-my-esperanto). Seems to be kinda sorta the opposite challenge.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/118466/58974)

Comment: That one reminded me of https://geekandpoke.typepad.com/geekandpoke/2011/08/coders-love-unicode.html ;-)

Comment: I don't understand if the challenge is about replacing a single word or entire text blocks, ie whether to deal with word separation.

Comment: Why is it necessary to replace both types? This is a really awkward input format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Perl 5 (`-pC -MUnicode::Normalize -Mutf8 -MList::Util=max`), <s>63</s>, <s>58</s>, 53 bytes

```
$_=NFD$_;s/([oau])\K̈(?=(.?))/max($1,$2)lt a?E:e/gei
```

[try it online](https://tio.run/##Zc/BSsQwEIDhe54ihx5acC0KgkRKIVov6vZiTypLko7rQNuUJAXxCfYh@ije9rrPZExy3VM@5h8GMoMZbrzPdtX28SHb3dkyf9Ni@Sjen06HvK7yy7ooylF859nVRXZdDI6KumFQ7gG9fwXrqBIWLF0sTns6G1B6nLWFnqovYYRyYCw5/tKKLhBemSCDeBInxzWgC22VCaGtsXUNJ2f3w3GJU1SPQhl0qCzRp0PY1xAhk2QkT@SkTbmFCJkkI2NuG/6nZ4d6sn4z3/vNyzNax1jncKjCp8Ogm1DpHhjbajOKAX8gDBf3efsP)

Comment: saved bytes using `-Mutf8` and chaging `\x{308}` by unicode character

Answer (score 2):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 112 bytes

```apl
[öäüÖÄÜ].?
.̈.?
1(819⌶⍣(2=+/M≠819⌶M))(∊'oauOAU'M)['öäüÖÄÜ'⍳⊃M]'e',⍵p↓1↓M←⍵M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcyxSsQwGMDxPU@RLS3qSZ10OKQ5MjiEDmkHOW5o2iAZvNRqn0A56mFBEJw6CPoG4k23Zb2nyIvUL3FxSPL78ofvrivrdpqWdme/7N6@2yc7rmaXaHbo4U6i8@TCvezc8BmdzY9OuXv@@PvhcRy5fktM2WVpQXi8JP9XEDd8u@0jXxFFjt3w07jNWwKHu80rjHyaxLXIGU/zqwXOmcjxIhVMoKZVJ5W5bcy9qpHd4znuFLwyQIJoEEV2BBTQRhkAbfStYBTBAqnXen2Da11WD7rVFTKHHqpRHjJIetJAirKQM@Uhg6Snzxmjvw)

*Replace…*

`[öäüÖÄÜ].?` any umlaut'ed character, optionally followed by a character

*… or…*

`.̈.?` any character and a combining umlaut, optionally followed by a character

*… with the result of the following function:*

`⍵M` the **M**atch
 `M←` store in `M`
 `1↓` drop one character from the left
 `⍵p↓` drop one character if match had combing umlaut (`⍵p` is 0-indexed pattern number)
 …`'e',` prepend the following character and an **e**:
  `(`…`)[`…`]` index using:
   `⊃M` the first character of the **M**atch
   `'öäüÖÄÜ'⍳` …'s index in the list of umlaut'ed characters
  … into:
   `'oauOAU'M` the two-element list of the de-umlaut'ed characters and the **M**atch
   `∊` **e**nlisted (flattened)
 `1(`…`)` apply the following derived function with 1 as left argument:
  `819⌶⍣(`…`)` casefold (to uppercase, because left argument would be 1) if:
   `819⌶M` the lowercased **M**atch
   `M≠` Boolean where the **M**atch differs from that (i.e. is uppercase)
   `+/` sum that
   `2=` 2 is equal to that

Equivalent to the tacit Dyalog APL function:

```apl
'[öäüÖÄÜ].?' '.̈.?'⎕R{1(819⌶⍣(2=+/M≠819⌶M))(∊'oauOAU'M)['öäüÖÄÜ'⍳⊃M]'e',⍵.PatternNum↓1↓M←⍵.Match}
```